# Excel doesn't give 'file in use pop-up' when other user's file is in sleep

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, file-server, microsoft-excel-365

When *\\server\file.xlsx* is opened in read/write by user 1 & user 2 tries to open *\\server\file.xlsx*, user 2 gets promped with "file already in use by user 1, open in read only or notify." as it should be.

When I look at the fileserver - Computer Management - System Tools - Shared Folders - Open Files, it shows *\\server\~$file.xlsx* correctly.

The problem is when the computer of user 1 goes into sleepmode, with *\\server\file.xlsx* opened, *\\server\~$file.xlsx* disappears & user 2 can open *\\server\file.xlsx* in read/write mode without the error prompt that the file is already in use. When user 1 logs back in, his *\\server\file.xlsx* is open and he doesn't get the error prompt either, only when he tries to save the file.

- Is there any configuration not done corectly on my side? (sysadmin)
- Are there any settings that have to be changed on either windows 10, Excel or the fileserver?
- Do I have educate my users to close their excel files before leaving their computer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known normal behavior that the connection between the client and server will be dropped if the client is in sleep mode.

After Excel client loses connection to the network workbook on the server, the workbook will be released and the temporary file will be deleted. Currently, the status of the workbook is back to Unlocked. Other Users can open the workbook without any error prompt.

When the clients awakes, Excel can keep previous editing and can't save it back to the network workbook because the workbook is locked by other user and connection is broken.

Yes, you can have educate your users to close their excel files on network shared drivers before leaving their computers.

Answer (score 0):

The client loses connection when it goes into sleep. You could do one of these:

1. Tell your users to save their file and close it when sleeping, or
2. Upgrade to a newer version of office (if possible) that supports multi-user editing.